# Use of transaction in MSSQL, update several tables

Tags: sql-server

I need a sanity check ;[, a customer of mine says he is seeing data at a time when I think he should not.

example, update 2 tables

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  update table1...
  update table2...
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

question - it is possible for a separate connection in the database to be triggered to read the updates to table1 before the updates in table2 are done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can if you set the isolation level of the other reading transaction to read uncommited.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763(v=sql.110).aspx.

It's easy to test if you start up two Sql Management Studios and run the transaction without commiting in one window, then try to select in the other window with different Isolation Levels.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, if your isolation level is set to read uncommitted.

Look at the isolation level provided by:

```
dbcc useroptions
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/24/sql-server-check-the-isolation-level-with-dbcc-useroptions/